# Convergence to equilibrium for Markov chains

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

The following theorem is from *Marikov Chains* by Norris:

> [image]

I don't understand the "In particular" part. In the first limit, $P(X_n=j)$ depends not only on the transition probability matrix $P$ but also the initial distribution $\lambda$. But in the second limit, the $n$-step transition probability $p_{ij}^{n}$ only depends on the transition probability matrix $P$. How would the second one be a particular case of the first one?

Comment: After enough time, the initial distribution doesn't matter.

Comment: Note that $p_{ij}^n $ is just the same as $P(X_n=j)$ where the initial distribution is $\delta_i$.

Comment: @Shalop: Stupid me. I didn't notice that this is rather trivial, thanks. If you could write your comment as an answer, I would accept it.